# google shell programmatically download reviews from google play

Tags: download, review, google-cloud-shell

so I have opened a google cloud platform account and would like to programmatically download my apps reviews from Google Play Store.
On a [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?visit_id=1-636219487791314511-3973716693&p=reviews_export&rd=1#export) page it says that I could do this with gsutil.
I tried the example code:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789/reviews/reviews_com.example.app_2014* /your/local/directory
```

Replacing the examples. But I cant get it to work. It says 'No URLs matched'

1) What do I do wrong?

2) I dont think this command programmatically downloads this report everyday, how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command would actually work. The problem was that I did not initiate `gcloud` and allowed my Google account access to my local machine.

So downloading `gcloud`, installing it and then initiate with `gcloud init` will do the trick.